# Textarea lines detection

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I'm using the code below to detect the amount of lines in a HTML `textarea`

```
$('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
    var text = $(".writeLines").val();
    var lines = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
    var count = lines.length;
    if (count > 5) {
        return false
    }
});
```

This works fine, but people seem to keep finding ways around this count checker by using blank lines or lines with just a space in them. For our system it's required to have content on each of those lines, what'd be a good way to get this done?

I'm aware this can be bypassed by the user, so perhaps we should use a PHP solution for this?

Comment: If user really want to, they can always modify your checking function if you are using javascript

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but we'll catch that in our back-end as well.

Comment: Did you do the check in the backend yet?

Comment: `people seem to keep finding ways around this count checker by using blank lines or lines with just a space in them` - i don't understand how these scenarios fail in your code... it seems to me there would still be line endings

Comment: The regex should really be `/\r\n|\n|\r/` since the alternatives are considered from left to right. The string `line\r\nbreak` would be split in `["line", "", "break"]` since `\r` is found as a separator first and `\r\n` is not even considered.

Comment: No I didn't because the back-end is in PHP. For the user there is no advantage by modifying this (long story) so the best way to do this is in Javascript I assume.

Comment: @Xufox I tried that but it'd still add an empty line to the count and it will still accept lines with just a single space in them.

Comment: If you want to consider blank lines and lines with spaces as “one” line break, then use `/[\n\r]\s*/` in your `split`. Still, what is an empty line? Is `"\u2062"` empty? Is `"\u2028"` a line break? As a user, I could simply add `sdf` to a line in order to add to the line count, right?

Comment: Yes, to give you an idea: user has to enter a list of comments in this box. The minimum is always 5 and the maximum depends on the product. Nowe we want to prevent users from entering less than 5 comments, what users often do is they only enter 2 and will fill-up the rest with enter's or white lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over all the lines, trim them and then test the length when the `keyCode` is `13` like this:

```
for(let i of lines){
  if(e.keyCode == 13 && i.trim().length == 0) e.preventDefault()
}
```

You could also use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of a loop:

```
e.keyCode == 13 && lines.some(line => line.trim().length == 0) && e.preventDefault()
```

```js
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
  var text = $(".writeLines").val()
  var lines = text.split(/\r\n|\n/)
  // Disable enter on empty line
  e.keyCode == 13 && lines.some(line => line.trim().length == 0) && e.preventDefault()
  // Disable enter if there are 5 lines
  e.keyCode == 13 && lines.length >= 5 && e.preventDefault()
})
// Disable pasting completely
.on('paste', e => e.preventDefault());

// When submitting:
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  var lines = text.split(/\r\n|\n/)
  (lines.some(line => line.trim().length == 0) || lines.length > 5) && e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="writeLines" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
```

Comment: This looks perfect! One question left, if I write a new line but then remove the characters in that line and press backspace (to completely remove the line) the count will go up with 1?

Comment: No, the code evalues the number of lines on every key press

Comment: I noticed this does protect from copy and paste that contain a new line. I will update the code to help prevent that.

Comment: I updated the code, I think this will work. Note that I changed `keydown` to `input` as well

Comment: I tried the code but with this code it's possible to have a blank line but press enter again?

Comment: We can disable `paste` completely with `on('paste')` this can be enhanced if needed. I also change `input` back to `keydown`

Comment: Yes that solves it again! It's almost perfect now, just wondering what'd be the best way to get the exact line count now? Since `lines.length` is not 100% accurate because when the line is stil empty it shouldn't count yet

Comment: I have added a second jQuery event on the `form` (assuming there is one) which checks to make sure all lines have data, if not then the form doesn't submit.

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible solution:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Ilan's Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="results">
                <textarea class="writeLines" cols="25" rows="25"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
   </div>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Set the initial counter
    var count = 0;
    // On press function
        $('.writeLines').keypress(function(e) {
            // Check the count, if it's less than 5 keep going
            if (count >= 5) {
                // Count is >= 5, for fun I disabled the textarea; you can do what you need here
                console.log('we hit 5 lines');
                $('.writeLines').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                return false
            } else {
                // Count is below 5, check is the enter key for a new line was pressed
                if(e.which == 13) {
                    // If the key is a new line (a return), add to the count and console log it
                    count = count + 1;
                    console.log('the current line count is: ' + count);
                } else {
                    // The key wasn't a new line, keep going and listen for the next key
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
 }); 
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```